# A named connection string was used, but the name 'DefaultConnection' was not found in the application's configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I have a `DbContext` named `FileManagerContext` in my DOTNET 6 API:

```
public class FileManagerContext : DbContext {
    public FileManagerContext(DbContextOptions<FileManagerContext> options) : base(options) { }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
    }
}
```

It's a pretty simple `DbContext` with a simple Entity in it. Anyway, I have this `appsettings.json` too:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=FM;User=SA;Password=1234;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And here is the startup snippet in `Program.cs`'s top level statement:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<FileManagerContext>(
    opt => opt.UseSqlServer("name=DefaultConnection"));
```

I could use migrations in the case. All thing goes good. I can add migrations and I can update database successfully. But when I run the application and try to use `DbContext` I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A named connection string was used,
> but the name 'DefaultConnection' was not found in the application's
> configuration. Note that named connection strings are only supported
> when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider, such as in a
> typical ASP.NET Core application. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850912 for more information.

I've also tried to get the connection string like this:

```
var cs = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

But it returns null. Can anybody help me through please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks To [@Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70958713/645167) I figured it out. The configurations were not loaded into app. But, since I'm in dotnet 6's top level statements, adding configurations seems a little bit different from @Neil's advice. So here is the working solution:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var currentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var environmentName = builder.Environment.EnvironmentName;

builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(currentDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

// blah blah 
builder.Services.AddDbContext<FileManagerContext>(
    opt => opt.UseSqlServer("name=DefaultConnection"));
```

Comment: Having same above issue , used above code but still its not working

Comment: This is a misleading answer.  This is completely redundant to the default convention of `WebApplication.CreateBuilder()`

Comment: I second @AdamVincent in this. It seems like OP is actually having an issue with context path

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds of the error, your configuration might not be getting picked up.

How is the configuration being created?

Do you see AddConfiguration extension method being called on the Webhost? the contents of the method should look something like the following:

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                          .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, false)                                           
                          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envLower}.json", true, true)
                          .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                          .Build();
```

The the call to build may or may not exist. We typically manually create the configuration object because we need to construct the Loggers and then use AddConfiguration extension method to add that object to the host.

If you don't see that, please take a look at the documentation from Microsoft for guidance on how to set it up. [Configuration Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Alternatively, you can get the connection string via the Configuration Object and pass it to the UseSqlServer method.

```
services.AddDbContext<FileManagerContext>((provider, options) => {
           IConfiguration config = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
           string connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
           options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);                             
         });
```

in the alternate method, a service provider is passed to the action. You can use the provider to fetch the IConfiguration object from the DI container.

Comment: the base path, json file (including environment overrides), environment variables, and even command-line parameters are all done by default in .NET core 6 with the single line `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but the error occurs when the application was published on the server. My string connection is in the user's secret, what I did was the following:

**In program.cs**

// Add services to the container.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer("Name=dbconnection");
});
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>();
```

And before publish, select the string connection in data base options and make sure it is the correct:

[Publish Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRCec.png)

It works for me in ASP.NET 6 API

Answer (score 1):

For the people reaching this question based on the google search of the error:

I got this error while running `Scaffold-DbContext` command, creating entities in DB first approach.

For me it was unrelated to the connection string altogether. It was due to an application runtime error where the DI was not able to resolve one of the repositories. I added the service in the `IServiceCollection` and it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Arrgh!  I had a similar problem, and tried all the answers here, but no luck.

Finally, it turned out that I had an `OnConfiguring` method in my DbContext:

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Name=ConnectionStrings:MyConnection");
```

When I removed those lines, everything worked!  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "name=DefaultConnection" since it is treated as connection string name including "name="

I am using this syntax in program.cs and everything is working properly

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

.......

builder.Services.AddDbContext<FileManagerContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

and since you are using Ms Sql Server , the connection string for sql server is usually like this

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=xxxx;Initial catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;"
```

and my OnConfiguring code looks like this

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
   {
       ...your code
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried without `name=`; no different. Also as I mentioned in Q `builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString` returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

use `builder.Configuration`

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<FileManagerContext>(options => 
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
});
```

or `builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString` as @Serge mentions

```
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to scaffold the DB changes by this command :

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection name=YourDBContextObjectName -Provider 
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -project Destination_NameSpace 
    -context YourDBContextObjectName -OutputDir Entities -force
```

But the issue is the same in the code-first approach as well, In my scenario, I had different **appsettings** for different ENVs.

[image]

The **appSettings.json** was like so (as you can see, there is **connectionStrings** information in this file:

[image]

Also, my **appsettings.dev.json** was like so :
[image]

The problem is being occurred because when I tried to scaffold the DB changes by command, Firstly it tries to build your project, and because the **Redis** and **RabbitMQ** connection information is missed in the **appsettings.json** file, It cannot connect to the dataSources. so It returns the error.

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> System.InvalidOperationException: A named connection string was used, but the name 'DBContextName' was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider...

**Solution :**

1. Set The correct Project as the **Startup project**
2. Add missing information about other connections to the **appsettings.json**

As you see, regardless of the error, It's not always related to the Database connection string.

Answer (score -4):

[Hello, the highlighted code worked for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCA88.png)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv8s2.png]

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [answer], read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418 ; and consider using https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32807284)